# How to set data type in Google Colab Input?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, integer, google-colaboratory

I tried to sum this equation on Google Colab

```
a=1
b=input("B:")
c=a+b
print(c)
```

I was googling, the offered solution is `c=a+int(b)` but an error happened `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Please help me to solve on how to sum c in Google Colab. Thanks a lot

Comment: I did tried `b = int(input("B:"))`, its not working too

Comment: Don't override `input`. Your code has `input = ...` somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no problem with the `c=a+int(b)` answer. Consider restarting your runtime.

[image]